# ODATA posting request in C# for an entity with navigation properties, creates new navigation properties

Tags: c#, post, foreign-keys, odata

I'm a newbie starting with Odata, and I've defined an Odata Api for the following entities:

```
[Table("clients", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Client
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }


}

[Table("orders", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Order
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    [Required]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public String Comment { get; set; }

}
```

The Name in the Client entity, and the Navigation Property in the Order entity are annotated as "required" because I use the Attribute Routing Api to validate the models in my controllers.

When Posting (insert) a new Order for the Client with Id 1 (which already exists in the database), I send a post request with the following json object in the body to my Odata endpoint:

```
{
  "Date": "2017-03-16T08:28:47.700Z",
  "Client": {
    "Id": 1
  },
  "Comment": "Something"
}
```

and I receive the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Order.Client.Name : Das Feld \"Name\" ist erforderlich.\r\n",
      "type": "",
      "stacktrace": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Translated into English, it means that the Field name for the entity Client is mandatory.

First question: how can I Post / insert an entity which has a navigation property (fk) with Odata without sending the complete object representing the navigation property in the post request, with all the fields? Is it not possible to do it sending only the id / primary key for the navigation property?

If I send the complete entity used as navigation property in the request, then the Order is created in the database, but a strange thing happens: the navigation property "Client" is ignored, and a new client with the same name is created for this inserted entity...

I mean, the order is created in the table, but the client_id for the order is not 1, because a new client was created, using the name provided. But the id was ignored...

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the client forign key to the order and just post that. This assumes that the client already exists and an order can only have one client.

Comment: But the clientId is already in the posted json object, isn't it? :S. And your assumptions are correct, the client exists, and an order can have only one client...

Comment: You are doing a post which means the odata will try to post (create) both the order and the client. The post ignores any key you provide and inserts a new client. Just add the client foreign key to the order.

`[ForeignKey("Client")]  
    public string ClientId { get; set; }  
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }  
`
}

Comment: [Entity Relations in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4)

Comment: The JSON provided in the question is correct ? There is no need to post to the $ref URL ?